# Itextsharp chunk problemm

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I have a strange problem when adding a chunk to a new pdf file using a writer.

```
Phrase f = new Phrase
{
    new Chunk("email: "),
    new Chunk("client@somewebaddress.com;"),
    new Chunk("www.somewebaddress.com")                        
};

cell = new PdfPCell(f)
{
    BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE,
    BorderWidth = 0,
    Colspan = 4
};
table.AddCell(cell);
```

When I open the file in Adobe acrobat and select `Document Menu...` `Examine document...` Acrobat finds on every page some hidden text, which is the `.` character from `somewebaddress.com`. How can I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: I just created a table with your cell and added it to a new document but Adobe Acrobat does not find any hidden text in the result file. So you seem not to provide all the information required for reproducing the issue. Please improve your question accordingly.

Comment: finally solved the issue, was drawing a dotted line under the table that caused the problem. Thanks.